# How can I run a script through crontab with a value input for the script?

Tags: linux, bash, script, bash-scripting, crontab

im trying to run a script with crontab on linux as follow, 
i create a script for a incremental backup.

when i excecute in the command line`/usr/bin/diego-backup.sh complete` the script creates a complete backup of the system `if not creates it incremental` the problem comes when i configure it to run through the crontab `0 0 * * *  (/usr/bin/diego-backup.sh complete && /usr/bin/diego-virt-starten.sh)` in this case the backup script creates a file that it is not a complete backup.

Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Script 1: Turns off all the Virtual Maschines

```
virsh shutdown Odoo
virsh shutdown OpenZ
virsh shutdown mssqlserver
virsh shutdown Zentyal_HOME
```

Script 2: Creates Backups

```
#cat > /usr/local/sbin/backup.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh
BACKUPDIR=/media/backup
LASTMONTHDIR=lastmonth
TSNAME=timestamp.snar
BACKUPNAME=backup
DIRS="/"
if [ $1 == "complete" ]; then
    #Komplettes Backup
    MYDATE=complete
    #Alte Timestamps löschen
    rm -f "$BACKUPDIR/$TSNAME"
    #Alte Backups löschen
    rm -rf "$BACKUPDIR/$LASTMONTHDIR.$BACKUPNAME.d"
    #Neue alte Backups in Ordner verschieben
    mkdir "$BACKUPDIR/$LASTMONTHDIR.$BACKUPNAME.d"
    mv -f "$BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPNAME.*".tgz
"$BACKUPDIR/$LASTMONTHDIR.$BACKUPNAME.d"
else
    #Inkrementelles Backup
    MYDATE=$(date +%y%m%d)
fi
#Abzug erstellen
tar czf "$BACKUPDIR"/"$BACKUPNAME".$MYDATE.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/media --exclude=/mnt$
#EOF chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/backup.sh
```

Script 3: Starts the Virtual Machines

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo echo "Starte die Virtual Maschinen an..."
xmlfiles=( $(find /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart/ -name '*.xml') )
for f in "${xmlfiles[@]}" ; do
 domain=$(xml2 < $f | awk -F= '$1 == "/domain/name" {print $2}')
  # only start domain if it's not already running
  if ! virsh list | grep  " ${domain} .*running" ; then
    virsh start "$domain"
  #else
    # optionally reboot domain otherwise
    #virsh reboot "$domain" 
 fi
done
```

Crontab like this:

```
41 12 * * * /usr/bin/diego-virt-stoppen.sh >> /home/sysadm/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`-virt-stop.log 2>&1
48 15 * * * (/usr/bin/diego-backup.sh complete && /usr/bin/diego-virt-starten.sh) >> /home/sysadm/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%$`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not without some more information.

Comment: what kind of information?

Comment: Post your scripts, for example.

Comment: Ready, took a while.

Comment: Question 1: Where is the `virsh` executable? cron jobs run with a very minimal path, so the start and stop scripts might not be finding it. Second, what do you get if you capture the error output from the backup script? (For that matter, what's the output you get in the existing logging?)

Comment: Q1: Virsh is under `virsh: /usr/bin/virsh /usr/share/man/man1/virsh.1.gz`

Comment: Q2: The Script runned and gave this today at 00:15  `/usr/bin/diego-backup.sh: 11: [: complete: unexpected operator`
`tar: Removing leading /' from member names`
`tar: /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432: socket ignored`
`tar: /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: socket ignored`
´` Starte die Virtual Maschinen an...`
`Domain mssqlserver started`
`Domain Zentyal_HOME started`
`Domain Odoo started`
`Domain OpenZ started`

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
/usr/bin/diego-backup.sh: 11: [: complete: unexpected operator
```

indicates a problem with this comparison:

```
if [ $1 == "complete" ]; then
```

(Note: that's not line 11 of the shown script; did some blank lines get left out?)

The problem is that `==` is a nonstandard comparison operator for the `[` command. `bash`'s builtin version of `[` accepts `==` as a synonym for `=`, but I'm guessing you're running this on a recent version of Debian or Ubuntu, where [/bin/sh is `dash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), a much more basic shell. `dash`'s builtin version of  `[` does not support `==`, and gives exactly the reported error message:

```
$ [ complete == complete ] && echo "Match succeeded" || echo "Match failed"
sh: 1: [: complete: unexpected operator
Match failed
```

You could solve this by switching to the standard `=` comparison:

```
$ [ complete = complete ] && echo "Match succeeded" || echo "Match failed"
Match succeeded
```

or by changing the script's shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), so the script will run in `bash` instead of `dash`. I'd actually recommend making both changes, and changing the shebang in all your scripts; there's no point in using something nonstandard in `bash` when the standard form works just as well, but also if you're not very familiar with what's standard vs. bashisms, it's safer to force `bash` so you won't trip over something like this again.

(Come to think of it, I don't know why your third script is working. It uses arrays, which are another thing that `bash` supports but `dash` doesn't.)

BTW, I have some other recommendations:

- Whichever form of the comparison you use, you should double-quote the parameter reference to avoid trouble if it isn't exactly one word long (double-quoting the string `complete` is not necessary, but doesn't hurt):

  ```
  if [ "$1" = "complete" ]; then
  ```
- You should use lower- or mixed-case variable names (see paragraph 4 [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)). There are a lot of all-caps variable names with special meaning to the shell and/or other programs, and if you use of those by mistake it can cause weird results ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975060/bash-variable-doubles-in-value-why)).
- In this line:

  ```
  mv -f "$BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPNAME.*".tgz "$BACKUPDIR/$LASTMONTHDIR.$BACKUPNAME.d"
  ```

  ...the wildcard needs to be *outside* the quotes in order to expand:

  ```
  mv -f "$BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPNAME".*.tgz "$BACKUPDIR/$LASTMONTHDIR.$BACKUPNAME.d"
  ```
- I'd feel safer if the scripts (especially the second) had some error checking. For example, if creating the new `$BACKUPNAME.d` directory fails for some reason, it's doesn't make sense for the script to blindly continue on and try to move the old files into the non-directory. You could use `set -e` (or add `-e` to the shebang) to make it exit if any command fails, but that can have [unexpected results](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). Personally, I prefer to force myself to think about each step in a script, the consequences should it fail, and explicitly script to handle them:

  ```
  rm -f "$BACKUPDIR/$TSNAME" || {
      echo "$0: Error deleting backup timestamps; cancelling backup" >&2
      echo "$0: A human will need to debug this before it can proceed" >&2
      exit 1
  }
  ```
- Finally, `sudo` isn't doing anything useful here:

  ```
  sudo echo "Starte die Virtual Maschinen an..."
  ```